# Working out position and velocity vectors at time t from constant rotation and acceleration

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out a forumula to get position and velocity at any point in time for an object with constant accelearation but vector of which is rotating.

I'm struggling to break down the problem into smaller pieces, it seems that its just a trig problem.

Lets say the object sits at `0,0` has an acceleration vector of `0,1` m/s (so up). <strike>and rotation of 1 rpm clockwise.</strike> The acceleration vector is rotated clockwise at 1 rpm.

As time goes by, it should trace a semi-circle, as acceleration vector turns clockwise, and starts to contribute to velocity to the right. When it completes 1 revolution, it should come to a dead stop, but be some distance to the right.

The acceleration and rotation somehow both govern how far and how fast the object will go.

The "real world" thing I'm modelling is a simplistic 2d space ship physics. Simplistic because only the following forces are present:

The ship has constant clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation, and constant thrust vector, which rotates with it.

Given a starting velocity vector perpendicular to the thrust vector, its possible for the ship to create an "artificial orbit" around a fixed point in space. That shape will be a circle. As long as the thrust vector always points at the centre of the orbit, and all the variables are balanced (thrust, rotation, and initial velocity), the orbit will be perfectly circular.

If they are not ballanced, the ship will simply tumble in space, not gaining any overall velocity, just temporarily moving around a shape that looks like if you drew a circle, but translated the centre to the right by x (if the rotation is counter clockwise, the translation would be to the left). I can't find the name of such spiral.

I'm pretty sure the thrust vector is `(cos(at), sin(at))`, because at bearing 0, x component is 1, y component is 0, and it carries on around the circle as it rotates. That vector multiplied by thrust factor, seems to be correct.

The velocity integral `(sin(at)/a,-cos(at)/a)` doesn't seem right. At `t=0` both x and y components should be 0, since we haven't spent any time "under the curve", yet `-cos(0*0)/1` is -1. (smaller values of a, for slower rotation give larger negative y values, which doesn't sound right)

This seems to graph the correct position:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iycc3jodph

Its weird that I have to use different formulas for negative rotations

Comment: Do you mean that you want to calculate the trajectory of a point-like object whose acceleration is of the form $\mathbf{a}(t)=(\cos(\alpha t), \sin(\alpha t))$? If that is the case you only need to integrate to get the velocity
$$
\mathbf{v}(t) = \int_{0}^t \mathbf{a}(t') dt' = (\sin(\alpha t)/\alpha + v_0^x , -\cos(\alpha t)/\alpha + v_0^y)
$$
and then integrate again to get the general position
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = ... = (-\cos(\alpha t)/\alpha^2+v_0^x t + x_0,-\sin(\alpha t)/\alpha^2+v_0^y t + y_0)
$$

Comment: How can it rotate if its acceleration is upwards? if you mean a physical system as in a charge subject to a northwards force but also placed on a rotating plate then something is strange, since you will need some kind of coefficient of friction, no?

Comment: may be you mean the object is subject to two forces, one that pushes it upwards and the other force is such that, in the absence of any other force, would make the object rotate around the origin at $-1$rpm. Is that what you mean?

Comment: `a(t)=(cos(αt),sin(αt))` is exactly right. `α` being the speed of rotation. The rotation and acceleration are independent. No other forces present

Comment: `a(t)=(cos(αt),sin(αt))`? So is the acceleration vector what is rotating and not the object? I think that's not the same as what you said in the post.

Comment: I don't think that's right, since in that case the net acceleration `a(t)=(cos(αt),1+sin(αt))` will never go downward.

Comment: I don't understand $v_0^x t$. This seems to be the initial velocity * time, but initial velocity  is 0 in the example. When I plug the position function into my code, I get my object just rotating around a static point. From my understanding, there should be some added velocity 90 degrees right or left of the acceleration vector, depending on the direction of rotation

Comment: Well the acceleration vector is rotating with the object, and is pointing in whatever direction the object is pointing, but I think I can normalise that out using vector calculations. My coordinate system actually has rotation as a bearing, 0 being +x.

Comment: Oh, so it's the coordinate system what is rotating. That makes more sense.

Comment: @YarekT I think I got it, but to confirm, is the initial accelerarion $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$? same question for initial velocity. And you say that the acceleration vector rotates clockwise, right? or is it anticlockwise?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz The initial acceleration actually depends on some other variables: thrust factor, initial ship bearing, but I can work thouse out by simple vector math. In my coordinate system its easiest to go with (0, 1) as the acceleration vector. Same deal with rotation, its either + or - based on the direction, and has a factor as well. I should probably measure it in a better unit. Radians per frame (a frame is second / 60) or something

Comment: Again, using identity for those is fine. It would be great if rotation somehow worked with the sign, so I didn't have to swap out the formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an initial acceleration
$$
a(0)=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\ a_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
an initial velocity
$$
v(0)=
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\ v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and initial position
$$
p(0)=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 \\ p_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Your acceleration vector is given by the initial acceleration rotating at $\omega$ radians per second, so multiply $a(0)$ by that rotation matrix:
$$
a(t)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t) \\
\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
a(0).
$$
Velocity is given integrating once
\begin{align}
v(t)
&=
v(0)+\int_0^t
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega u) & -\sin(\omega u) \\
\sin(\omega u) & \cos(\omega u)
\end{bmatrix}
a(0)\,du \\
&=
v(0)+\frac{1}{\omega}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)-1 \\
-\cos(\omega t)+1 & \sin(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
a(0) \\
&= v(0)
+
\frac{1}{\omega}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
a(0)
+\frac{1}{\omega}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) \\
-\cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
a(0).
\end{align}
And integrate again for position
\begin{align}
p(t)
&=
p(0)
+
\int_0^t v(u)\,du \\
&= p(0)
+
t
\left(v(0)
+
\frac{1}{\omega}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
a(0)
\right)
+\frac{1}{\omega^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
-\cos(\omega t)+1 & \sin(\omega t) \\
-\sin(\omega t) & -\cos(\omega t)+1
\end{bmatrix}
a(0) \\
&= p(0)
+
\frac{1}{\omega^2}a(0)
+
t
\left(v(0)
+
\frac{1}{\omega}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
a(0)
\right)
-\frac{1}{\omega^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t) \\
\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
a(0) \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1 + \frac{1}{\omega^2}a_1
\\
p_2 + \frac{1}{\omega^2}a_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
t
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 - \frac{1}{\omega} a_2 \\
v_2 + \frac{1}{\omega} a_1
\end{bmatrix}
-
\frac{1}{\omega^2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t) \\
\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1
\\
a_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
For $a(0)=(0,1)$, $v(0)=(-1,0)$, $p(0)=(0,0)$ and $\omega=-2\pi/60$ (1 revolution per minute counterclockwise) you get this.

[image: trajectory]

With $v(0)=(0,0)$ you get nice arcs. With $v(0)=\frac{1}{\omega}(a_2,-a_1)$, you get a perfect circular orbit. [Here is the Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hq5kebnjvf).

Comment: Yes, exactly right! Thanks for the solution, and taking the time to understand what I mean

Answer (score 1):

If the particle moves upwards with acceleration $(0,1)$ m/s² its velocity will be $(0,t)$ m/s and its position will be given by
$$
p(t) = \frac{t^2}{2}(0,1)
$$
in a non-rotating coordinate system.

Now, if your coordinate system is rotating at $\omega$ radians per second in the positive direction, this position now becomes
$$
p(t) = \frac{t^2}{2}(\sin(\omega t),\cos(\omega t))
$$

Since $\omega$ is given in rad/s and you want 2pi rad/minute, then
$$
\omega = \frac{2\pi}{60}
$$
so that
$$
p(t) = \frac{t^2}{2}\left(\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{60} t\right),\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{60} t\right)\right)
$$
where time is given in seconds.

I plotted the trajectory in Desmos:

[image: rotating object]

and [here is the link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kos79j7fhm).

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Hmm, something here doesn't add up. The velocity vector of the particle shouldn't be rotating, just its acceleration vector. Once the rotation makes one full turn its overall velocity should be cancelled out (i think), given the fact that as the acceleration rotates around a circle, it spent equal time in each axis. It should come to a dead stop, having traced a semi-circle sort of shape.

Comment: This is the closest graph I can get: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=parametric+plot+%28sinx+%2B+x%2C+cosx%2Bx%29+where+x+from+-10+to+10 As the object gets to that corner, its velocity is 0, II The graph isn't quite right though, I don't get where the vertical y translation comes from

Comment: Another example is a regular circular orbit. If the object starts with initial "orbital" velocity, and has a force acting that pulls it round the orbit, it will trace a circle. The initial velocity, and the radial in force has to match the orbit size though.

Comment: If the velocity weren't rotating, acceleration wouldn't either. That graph would have been helpful if you put it in the original question.

Comment: @YarekT so do you want the trajectory of an object in circular orbit around an axis, and that axis moves with uniform acceleration in the vertical direction? That would look kinda like a spiral. Are you trying to model something in the real world? you can fill the original post with these extra details. It would be helpful to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, and no. Its possible to create a circular orbit by applying force in the right direction, but if the direction of the force isn't aimed at the centre of the orbit, then it won't be a circle anymore. I'll update the question with more detail